# django import local settings from the server

Tags: python, django

In my home directory, I have a folder called `local`. In it, there are files called `__init__.py` and `local_settings.py`. My django app is in a completely different directory. When the app is **NOT** running in DEBUG mode, I want it to load the `local_settings.py` file. How can this be acheived? I read the below:

[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

[Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Basically, those tutorials are allowing to import from another directory, but what about a completely different working tree? I don't want to keep doing .., .., .. etc. Is there a way to goto the home directory?

I tried the following code:

```
import os, sys
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), 'local'))
from local_settings import *
```

But i keep seeing errors in my apache error.log for it...

Comment: It would be better if you make the settings file in the same directory and specify it when you run the app.

Comment: I could..problem is that for deployment, these are local settings, not something I want on the source control. When I do a deployment, these would be overwritten or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.chdir` just affects the current working directory, which has nothing whatsoever to do with where Python imports modules from.

What you need to do is to add the the `local` directory to the Pythonpath. You can either do this from the shell by modifying `PYTHONPATH`, or from inside Python by modifying `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~/local"))
import local_settings
```

Comment: Worked! Except the `import` is missing `os`.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your concerns about source control, you can just set the source control to ignore that file, and/or have a  symlink installed as part of your deploy script to link the file on the os into another.  I do both , though not in django.  but it's a trivial task.

your deploy layout could look like this:

```
/current ( symlink to /releases/v3 )
/settings/local_settings.py
/releases/v1
/releases/v2
/releases/v3
```

and a task runs as part of your deploy:

```
cd /current 
ln -s /settings/local_settings.py local_settings.py
```

if you're deploying with fab or capistrano, it's a few lines of configuration.  i'm sure you could do this with puppet/chef simply too.